# Where is logback encoder pattern documentation

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

I've gone through all the [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/documentation.html) of [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) and I can't find anywhere the documentation to configure the encoder's pattern when logging, such as:

```xml
<encoder>
  <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-4relative %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
```

I would like a table (like the one that log4j has) explaining the different options to configure the pattern.

Where is the documentation of the pattern? Maybe they are defined in another project?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Probably you should take a look at [Chapter 6: Layouts](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord)...

Comment: I'm stupid. Sometimes something is in front of your eyes and you simply can't see it. I've went 3 times to that chapter and I didn't see it. Thanks!.

Comment: I too did not see it. About a quarter down that long page, in the [Conversion Word table](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord) of the [`PatternLayout`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicPatternLayout) section.

Comment: Ugh I dislike the documentation layout, the top sections always seem unrelated...

Comment: I don't think the '...' was aimed at you Pakore, more at how buried it is in their page, and how few people actually link to it.